# EKEvent occurrenceDate availability on iOS

Tags: ios, eventkit

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekevent/1507244-occurrencedate) for `EKEvent.occurrenceDate` mentions under Special Considerations, "This property is not available on iOS." However under the list of SDKs on the right side of that page it includes iOS 9.0+.

I can confirm that the property is available for events fetched by my app running on iOS 11.0. Can anyone confirm that this special consideration note is just left over from iOS 4.0-8.x and that there are no longer any special caveats for using it on iOS?

Comment: I'd suggest filing a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com), because either way you slice it, it's wrong. But I think you're right, that the documentation is just out of date, not reflecting that this was introduced in iOS 9. When there is a contradiction between headers and documentation, I always favor the headers over the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Rob. I'm filing a bug report now.